# Data structure for arithmetic logical queries

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, logic, search-algorithms

#### Abstract Problem

I'm looking for a data structure that will (1) allow me to make queries of the form `A.x - B.x <= 0.1 AND A.y + B.y >= C.y + D.y` and (2) allow reasonable (let's say `O(n)` is sufficient) updates to `x` and `y`. The query is meant to be read, "in the query space there are two objects, A and B, that are very close (for some measure of distance, "x") and sum to the greatest value of pairs of the space (for some measure of value, "y"). I imagine that some sort of SQL database would satisfy this but I'm looking for a data structure that I can implement on my own and that doesn't require an external dependency like SQL. For now, assume that no other types of queries on any other attributes are required, just ones of the aforementioned kind.

#### Concrete Example

For a concrete example, imagine you have a set of boxers for which you're going to select two, A and B, for a match. For the most interesting and popular match, the attributes you care about are their relative strengths, x, and influence / social media capabilities, y. You want to find the pair that minimizes the difference in their strengths (for match fairness) and maximizes the sum of their influence (for match popularity). Moreover, assume that these values regularly update in real-time (the analogy may breakdown here).

#### Naive Solution

A naive solution would be to compute these values for every combination of boxers and perform a filter and a sort. Given that these values update in real-time, this will become expensive since the relevant values of each pair need to be recomputed with each update and the recompute is `O(n^2)`.

#### Thoughts

Perhaps this is some sort of a heap problem? Or perhaps this requires a combination of data structures. I'm not sure. Thanks for any help finding the right data structure.

Comment: If there is a pair $(A,B)$ with the least value of $A.x - B.x$ and there is a different pair $(C,D)$ with highest value of $C.y + D.y$. Then, which pair do you choose?

Comment: What are the inputs to the query?  Can we choose $C,D$ however we want, or do you mean you want the equation to hold for all possible $C,D$?  What should the output/result of the query be? What is meant by "sum to the greatest value of pairs of the space"?

Comment: You are trying to optimize two separate objective functions.  There is not necessarily any single solution that maximizes both simultaneously.  In real life, typically there will be a tradeoff.  As a result, the problem is not well-specified.  To make it well-specified, you have to provide a way to describe how you want to trade off between those two objective functions.  See Pareto optimal front and multi-objective optimization.

Comment: You did not say what $n$ represents. And how large can it be ? But do you really need to recompute all inequalities for a change of $x$ or $y$ ?